# Can you put a dynamic pointer to a regular array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to code a scheduler in C for practice. Currently my issue is that I am trying to put the "student" object that i created into an array of students called "employees". So i create the student, get its schedule and then dereference the *student and put it in employees[i] array. But when I print the names in the employees array it prints the last entered name repeatedly. I also tried making employee array a pointer (Student *employee) but got the same problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank You
        ______________________________________________________________________________

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #define NUM_SLOTS 24
    #define NUM_EMPLOYEES 5
    #define BUFF 25
    #pragma warning(disable : 4996)
    typedef struct Student Student;
    typedef struct StudentDay StudentDay;
    typedef struct Slot Slot;
    //array of strings of all the timeslots
    char *timeSlots[NUM_SLOTS] = { "08:00-08:30", "08:30-09:00", "09:00-09:30" , "09:30-10:00" , "10:00-10:30" , "10:30-11:00" , "11:00-11:30" , "11:30-12:00",
                            "12:00-12:30", "12:30-13:00", "13:00-13:30", "13:30-14:00", "14:00-14:30", "14:30-15:00", "15:00-15:30", "15:30-16:00", "16:00-16:30",
                            "16:30-17:00", "17:00-17:30", "17:30-18:00", "18:00-18:30", "18:30-19:00", "19:00-19:30", "19:30-20:00"
    };
    char *daysOfWeek = "MTWRFS";

    //data structure represents a day for a student
    typedef struct StudentDay {
        char name;
        //binary slots representing 1 for available -1 for unavailable
        int slots[NUM_SLOTS];
    };

    //data structure represents a student
    typedef struct Student {
        char *name;
        //array of 24 half hour times starting 8am - 8pm
         StudentDay week[6];
    };

    //data structure represents a time slot in a day
    typedef struct Slot{
        char *time;
        char *personAssigned;
        int done; // 1 if done assinging
    };

    //data structure represents a day for coach will
    typedef struct WorkDay {
        char *name;
        Slot slots[NUM_SLOTS];
    };
    int main() {
        printf("Collin College Fitness Center Scheduling System\n");

        int numEmployees;
        printf("Please enter number of employees\n");
        scanf("%d", &numEmployees);

        //create an array of student employees
        Student employees[BUFF];
        //enter which day are you scheduling for
        printf("What day are you wanting to schedule, Enter M-Mon, T-Tue, W-Wed, R-Thu, F-Fri, S-Sat?\n");
        char day = getchar();
        //will possibly need another loop for all siz days right now just one day ex. monday M
        for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++) {
            Student *student = malloc(sizeof(Student));
            //setting name for student
            char name[BUFF];
            printf("Please enter name for emplyee number %d\n", i + 1);
            fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
            student->name = name;

            printf("Enter the student's class times in military format Example 13:00-14:30 and press enter, input Done when done\n");
            //time stores the input class time by coach
            char time[BUFF] = "";
            while (strcmp(time, "done") != 1 || strcmp(time, "Done") != 1) {
                fgets(time, sizeof(time), stdin);
                char *temp = time;
                //get the index of the class' time slot
                int indexOfSlot = getIndexOfString(timeSlots, temp);
                //get index of the day we are scheduling for
                int dayIndex = getIndexOfChar(daysOfWeek, day);
                //for this students particular days' this time slot is made unavailable
                student->week[dayIndex].slots[indexOfSlot] = -1;
            }
            //put this students info in the employees array
            employees[i] = *student;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            printf("employee stored is %s", employees[k].name);
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    //helper method to get the index of a string in an array
    int getIndexOfString(char*names[NUM_SLOTS], char *name) {

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SLOTS; i++) {
            if (strcmp(names[i], name) == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //helper method to get te index of char in a string
    int getIndexOfChar(char *name, char c) {
        char *temp = name;
        int i = 0;
        while (*temp != '\0') {
            if (*temp == c) {
                return i;
            }
            temp++;
            i++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array `name` is created locally and overwritten on every iteration.  You need to allocate a separate string in the heap for every student.

Replace this:

```
char name[BUFF];
...
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

With this:

```
char* name = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFF);
...
fgets(name, BUFF, stdin);
```